# Java/Android - Immutable Strings for child objects

Tags: java, string, inheritance, superclass

I have 3 Java classes: Class1, Class2 and Class3.

```
public class Class1 {
    ArrayList<Class3> arrayOfObjects;

    public Class1() {
        if (arrayOfObjects == null){
            arrayOfObjects = new ArrayList<Class3>
        }
    }
}

public class Class2{
    public String mName;

    public Class2(String name){
        this.mName = name;
    }
}


public class Class3 extends Class2{
    public Class3(String name){
        super(name);
    }
}
```

Each instance of Class1 contains an ArrayList of  Objects. My problem is, since Strings are immutable, How can i get all of the child objects of Class3 to update their "mName" Variable when it is changed in Class2? I have tried using For loops and looping through everything, which works fine, but as the lists grow larger and larger so does the time involved.

Comment: You don't need to declare `mName` in `Class3` as it already inherits that field from `Class2`. I'm not entirely sure what you are even asking though. Did you mean for it to be `public static String mName;`?

Comment: You are correct, I actually have that in my code, error in typing it out. Will edit now.

Comment: Constructors should maintain an object invariant, so its bad design to provide a value through a constructor and completely change it afterwards. Nevertheless, if you want to change values in every object, you have to access every object, that's how Java works.

Comment: Would you mind expanding a little bit about "should maintain an object invariant"?

Comment: Your question still does not makes sense to me. Do you understand polymorphism in Java?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to cascade a change to all the child object when the parents name changed, but since Strings are immutable they do not change. I was looking for the best method of going about it besides huge loops through everything per change.

Comment: Where in your question is the "parent object" and the "child object"? Is `Class1` supposed to be a parent with it's own name?

Comment: Class1 contains an ArrayList of Class 3's, and Class 3's are created from Class 2's. My problem was getting Class 3's to change their name when their parent class 2 name changed.

Comment: Right - I don't think you fully understand what it means for a "Class 3 to be created from a Class 2". In the example you've given, there is no issue.  If your real code is more complicated than this, you may want to look in to the Observer pattern. But if your code is as it is here, with 3 inheriting from 2, there is no different "name", you are not shadowing any variable.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right about that. The problem was when Class 2's field "mName" changed, Class3's wouldn't. I figured that's because they were immutable and hence a different object all together. Would CharSequence be a possible solution?

Comment: Your question really makes no sense - there is no cascading here - a `Class2` is the superclass of `Class3`, but after object creation the two are not linked. If we rename them to something more sensible like `Animal` and `Dog` then if you have an Animal objed with the name "Fred" that is not transferrable to a new Dog object unless you specifically set the Dog's name to be that. If you do want to have an Animal and a Dog both, essentially, point to the same name, polymorphism isn't involved there - as @DougMoscrop suggested, the Observer pattern is what you'd need.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Disclaimer

This is a pretty long winded, very basic tutorial on variable shadowing, scope and static fields. With the edits to your question it doesn't really apply as much as it seemed to originally.
I started writing it though so figured I'd finish, maybe it will be of use to somebody or I'll find somewhere to migrate it to in the future...

---

You don't need to declare `mName` in `Class3` as it already inherits that field from its parent, `Class2`.

However, if you want to be able to make changes to any Class2 and see the results in Class3 then you need to know about `static variables`, `variable scope` and `variable shadowing`

---

### Variable Shadowing

If you declare another field in `Class3` with the same name as one that the Parent class also has then it 'shadows' or 'hides' the original field as Java will use the first variable with the correct name that it finds.

---

Consider a very simple base class like this:

```
public class Parent {
    public int myVariable = 5;

    public void printMyVariable() {
        System.out.println(myVariable);
    }
}
```

Now lets define some children:

```
public class ChildOne extends Parent {
    // nothing here
}

public class ChildTwo extends Parent {
    public void printMyVariable() {
        System.out.println(myVariable + 2);
    }
}

public class ChildThree extends Parent {
    public int myVariable = 10;
}

public class ChildFour extends Parent {
    public int myVariable = 99;

    public void printMyVariable() {
        int myVariable = 700;
        System.out.println(myVariable);
    }
```

Now lets take a look at how all those different values get read by the JVM:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    // make some objects:
    Parent parent = new Parent();
    ChildOne childOne = new ChildOne();
    ChildTwo childTwo = new ChildTwo();
    ChildThree childThree = new ChildThree();

    // print some values:
    parent.printMyVariable();
    childOne.printMyVariable();
    childTwo.printMyVariable();
    childThree.printMyVariable();
    childFour.printMyVariable()
}
```

This will print these values to your console:

```
5    // original parent class' base value

5    // does not try to override, mask, hide the parent's value or print

7    // printMyVariable() is defined again and the JVM uses
     //   the first matching method it finds which is in the ChildTwo class

10   // myVariable is defined in the class
     //   the class variable shadows the parent variable but the method
     //   still functions as expected

700  // myVariable is shadowed at the class level
     // but the print method also declares a myVariable
     // it is the method's version that gets found first and used
```

---

### Static Variables

Now all that is about 'instance variables'. These are variables that have their own unique value for every copy or Object that exists of them.
If you change `childOne's` myVariable is has no affect on `childTwo's` value or even another instance of ChileOne that you may have assigned eslewhere.

Were you to define those fields as `static` however, you are saying that you want to share the same variable and value across all copies or instances of that class.

```
public class Parent {
    public static int myStaticVariable = 25;
}

public class ChildOne extends Parent {
    // nada
}

public class ChildTwo extends Parent {
    public static int myStaticVariable = 99;
}
```

And if we now poke at the static variables:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    // a few classes
    Parent parent = new Parent();
    ChildOne childOne = new ChildOne();
    ChildOne childOneCopy = new childOne();
    ChildTwo childTwo = new childTwo();

    // take a peek at the values
    System.out.println(parent.myStaticVariable):
    System,out.println(childOne.myStaticVariable);
    System,out.println(childTwo.myStaticVariable);

    // let's change the value
    parent.myStaticVariable = 66;
    System.out.println(parent.myStaticVariable):
    System,out.println(childOne.myStaticVariable);
    System,out.println(childTwo.myStaticVariable);

    // and the two copies of ChildOne?
    childOne.myStaticVariable = 123;
    System,out.println(childOneCopy.myStaticVariable);
    childOneCopy.myStaticVariable = 456;
    System,out.println(childOne.myStaticVariable);
}
```

And these results:

```
25    // no surprise here

25    // ChildOne does not define its own variable so it uses the Parent's

99    // As in the earlier example the variable is getting shadowed


66    // we just changed the variable value so this looks normal

66    // even though it was the Parent's variable we changed
      //   the Child shares it too

99    // Since ChildTwo's variable is shadowing the Parent value it has not changed.


123   // 123? But we changed the original ChildOne...

456   // Again we modified the other object but since they share
      //   the same static variable; changing one also changes the other.
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a wrapper object for the String

```
public class MutableString
{
    private String value;
    public MutableString(String value)
    {
        this.value = value
    }
    public void set(String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

In your code, instead of storing strings, Class3 and Class2 would store references to objects of type MutableString